# Scraping between multiple html tags with same name

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract HTML between two HTML tags with identical id

```
html = '''<div id="note">

    <div id="seccion">
        <a name="title">Title of the seccion 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="col1">xxx</div>
        <div id="col2">xxx</div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="col1">xxx</div>
        <div id="col2">xxx</div>
    </div>

    <div id="seccion">
        <a name="title">Title of the seccion 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="block">
        <div id="col1">xxx</div>
        <div id="col2">xxx</div>
    </div>

    <div id="block">
        <div id="col1">xxx</div>
        <div id="col2">xxx</div>
    </div>

    <div id="seccion">
        <a name="title">Title of the seccion 3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="block">
        <div id="col1">xxx</div>
        <div id="col2">xxx</div>
    </div>

</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

seccion= soup.find_all("div", {"id": "seccion"})
for item in seccion:
    print([a.text for a in item.find_all("a", {"name": "title"})])
```

Unfortunately, sections are not separated in a div from which children are dropped.
In sections with  I don't know how many blocks there are.

I am not sure if it is posible to extract html between 2 divs when names are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate sections by using `.find_all()` with parameter `recursive=False` and then check if the `<div>` contains `id="seccion"` attribute.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

sections = []
for div in soup.select_one('div#note').find_all('div', recursive=False):
    if div.get('id') == 'seccion':
        sections.append([div])
    else:
        sections[-1].append(div)

for section in sections:
    for div in section:
        print(div.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints the three sections separated:

```
Title of the seccion 1
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title of the seccion 2
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title of the seccion 3
xxx
xxx
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Download driver for google Chrome [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

To get 'xpath' right click on the element then 'copy' and select 'Copy XPATH' or 'Copy Full XPATH'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless') #Opens Chrome in background
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Path_to_chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('url') #Webpage url
Text = driver.find_element("xpath","Element_xpath").Text #Get the label text
driver.close() #Close Chrome
```